# why ip address differs when wireless is off?

Tags: java, networking

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InetAddress myIp = null;

        try {
            myIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception cought.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println(myIp);
    }

}
```

I have this simple question that why my ip address is different when my wireless is off?
it's still the same computer, so why does it change? (isn't this a unique number?)

Comment: what is the ip when it is off? 127.0.0.1?

Comment: When wireless is on, does your computer connects to a network?

Comment: I upvoted to help. No reason for down vote here.  Valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IP address of the computer depends on the network it's connected to (and indeed, the same machine may have more than one, if it has multiple adapers).

So if I connect my machine to one of my networks, it may have the address `192.168.10.7` whereas on another of my networks, it may be `192.168.17.12`. It can vary between connections as well, although in practice they tend to be a bit sticky. (It depends on how the DHCP server is configured.)

Your adapter can be configured with a fixed address, but if you do that, it has to be an address the network it's connecting to has reserved for it. Otherwise it may not work at all ("No route to host") or may conflict with another machine using the network.

Comment: "although in practice they tend to be a bit sticky." Depends on the configuration of the related DHCP server. DNS doesn't apply to this directly.

Comment: @hexafraction: LOL I just was adding that, except I seem to have written DNS. (Oops)

Answer (score 1):

.An IP address is the address of a network adapter *within a specific local network*.

It will be different when connected to different networks.

When not connected to any network, it will either be a link-local address or an auto-configuration address.

You *might* want the MAC address, which is the hardware address of a single network adapter and is not very likely to change.

Answer (score 1):

The provided code returns HOSTNAME/IP-Address(xx.xx.xx.xx).

Hostname is your computer name ex: MY-PC and then you get the IP corresponding to it.
When you are connected to a network, InetAddress.getLocalHost() asks the DHCP server in the network "what is the address of MY-PC (the name of your computer)", the DHCP replies -> 33.44.55.66

Try the following CMD commands when both connected and disconnected.

```
\>hostname
MY-PC
\>nslookup MY-PC
44.55.66.77
```

When you are not connected to a network there are two possibilities:

1. You do not get a hostname (default is localhost)
2. You do get a hostname, but there is no DHCP server on the network to return an IPaddress,
   so you get loopback - 127.0.0.1

If you want to "call" your computer on the network locally, use the loopback http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/57812/loopback-address

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

No. You're confusing IP and MAC addresses. The MAC address is a serial number of hardware(but may be programatically changed on certain chipsets).

The IP address is either software-determined or determined by the network. It can differ between networks or even with time.

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses are (usually) *interface specific*, not *machine specific*.

If your machine only has one interface the difference is moot, but it matters if (for example) you have both wired and wireless ethernet.

Also note that if you do have both and attempt to use them both at the same time *on the same subnet* that things will likely get very confused!